# Windows service shut down

Tags: winapi, service, atl, shutdown

I use VS6 and ATL with CServiceModule to implement a custom windows service. In case of a fatal error service should shut itself down. Since CServiceModule is available via _Module variable in all files I thought of something like this to cause CServiceModule::Run to stop pumping messages and shut itself down

```
PostThreadMessage(_Module.dwThreadID, WM_QUIT, 0, 0);
```

Is this correct or you have better idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For self shutdown you send command to Service Manager. Try this sample :

```
BOOL StopServiceCmd ( const char * szServiceName )
{ 
    SC_HANDLE schService; 
    SC_HANDLE schSCManager; 
    SERVICE_STATUS ssStatus;       // current status of the service 
    BOOL bRet;
    int iCont=0;

    schSCManager = OpenSCManager( 
        NULL, // machine (NULL == local) 
        NULL, // database (NULL == default) 
        SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS // access required 
        ); 
    if ( schSCManager ) 
    { 
        schService = OpenService(schSCManager, szServiceName, SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS); 

        if (schService) 
        { 
            // try to stop the service 
            if ( ControlService( schService, SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP, &ssStatus ) ) 
            { 
                Sleep( 1000 ); 

                while( QueryServiceStatus( schService, &ssStatus ) ) 
                { 
                    iCont++;
                    if ( ssStatus.dwCurrentState == SERVICE_STOP_PENDING ) 
                    { 
                        Sleep( 1000 ); 
                        if ( iCont > 4 ) break;
                    } 
                    else 
                        break; 
                } 

                if ( ssStatus.dwCurrentState == SERVICE_STOPPED ) 
                    bRet = TRUE; 
                else 
                    bRet = FALSE; 
            } 

            CloseServiceHandle(schService); 
        } 
        else 
            bRet = FALSE; 

        CloseServiceHandle(schSCManager); 
    } 
    else 
        bRet = FALSE;

    return bRet;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if you do this, then the service manager will think that your service has crashed and if the user ever sets it up to auto-restart, it will.

In .NET, you use the ServiceController to signal your service to shut down. I expect it is similar in Win32 since most of this stuff in .NET is just wrappers. Sorry, I don't have C++ code handy to shut down the service, but here is the .NET code. This will hopefully help you Google the info you need, or find the docs in MSDN.

This is from some test suite code, thus the style of error checking ;) You will need to put this code in a thread so that the shutdown message gets handled.

```
  private void stopPLService( bool close )
  {
     if ( m_serviceController == null )
     {
        m_serviceController = new ServiceController( "PLService" );
     }

     WriteLine( "StopPLService" );

     if ( m_serviceController != null )
     {
        try
        {
           m_serviceController.Stop();
        }
        catch
        {
           // Probably just means that it wasn't running or installed, ignore
        }

        // Wait up to 30 seconds for the service to stop
        try
        {
           m_serviceController.WaitForStatus( ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, new TimeSpan( 0, 0, 30 ) );
        }
        catch ( System.ServiceProcess.TimeoutException )
        {
           Assert.Fail( "Timeout waiting for PLService to stop" );
        }
        catch
        {
           // Not installed, we only care in the start
        }
        if ( close )
        {
           m_serviceController.Close();
           m_serviceController = null;
        }
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the ControlService or [ControlServiceEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682110(VS.85).aspx) methods to shutdown your service. You should be able to get the required handle from the CServiceModule.